# Autocorrect python3 package error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi, autocorrect

I installed the autocorrect package using the command **pip install autocorrect** everything installed correctly but the Example code:

```
    from autocorrect import Speller
     check = Speller(lang='en')
    check("does this sentece have misspelled wordz?")
```

give me this error which in the package files:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\a.b.k\study\testauto.py", line 3, in 
>       check = Speller(lang='en')   File "C:\Users\Abdelrahman Bonna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\autocorrect__init__.py",
>   line 58, in **init**
>       self.nlp_data = load_from_tar(lang)   File "C:\Users\Abdelrahman Bonna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\autocorrect__init__.py",
>   line 52, in load_from_tar
>       return json.load(file)   File "C:\Users\Abdelrahman Bonna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json__init__.py",
>   line 268, in load
>       parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)   File
>   "C:\Users\Abdelrahman
>   Bonna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json__init__.py",
>   line 312, in loads
>       s.**class**.**name**)) TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

I am using python 3.5 with this package and ruining windows 10.